# What are the security risks of connecting to a VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables, openvpn, nat

Does connecting to a shared-IP VPN expose local ports to other users of the same VPN server? Does a VPN tunnel neutralize the protection offered by a NAT router? Are local ports reachable from a compromized VPN server? Assume OpenVPN.

Is this a matter of configuration of the OpenVPN server? If so, how to check? Is it necessary to explicitly close the ports via local iptables rules even if machine is behind a NAT?

The closest I could find is [this](https://www.goldenfrog.com/vyprvpn/features/nat-firewall) (too vague) and [this](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/255-qconnection-initiated-with-xxxxq-but-i-cannot-ping-the-server-through-the-vpn) (unclear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, depending on the setup of the server, a shared-vpn can expose local ports to other users of the same VPN server, and it does bypass NAT.

Mitigating/fixing this is not so much a matter of configuration of the OpenVPN server as ensuring iptables is running on the local machine and blocking ports as appropriate.   Running a local firewall is always a good idea.

Its difficult to check as it depends on the VPN setup of your provider and what access you have.  If you have 2 devices with VPN connections to the same provider you could use 1 device to portscan the other device to give you some comfort.

Also, security is not an either or, rather its built up of layers - In addition to looking at the forwarding of packets to your system, look at the apps you are running and see what can be done to lock them down - that way you can gain protection at a different layer.